# IBM Mobile First: user management and authentication

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, ibm-cloud, mobilefirst-adapters, mobilefirst-server

The documentation of the IBM mobile first has hardcoded samples on users are authenticated, the sample does not fetch users from some database or service. In practise where are the users and passwords expected to be stored? In IBM database and then accessed by SQLAdapter. Or some service external over http that an http adapter would call? Does MobileFirst  have an out of box user management feature? I do not have existing systems where the users are there and the users are expected to onboard with IBM mobile first server. The external services that I will call using http adapters will rely on IBM mobile first for users and permissions and roles. Need help on this.

Answer (score 0):

Usernames and passwords can be stored in various systems from various vendors, such as LDAP or Active Directory and alike.

See here for an example of LDAP: https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/blog/2016/07/17/connecting-to-LDAP-with-ibm-mobilefirst-foundation/

The blog post assumes you're using MobileFirst Foundation 8.0.

Comment: Idan, if one does'nt have LDAP or any other user management system and starting from scratch then what is the best option? Also what if most targeted users are consumers and in addition to system login need to support social login as well? Can we configure users in IBM Mobile first database itself, maybe using some sqladapter? If not, are there any LDAP service in bluemix or any product that is recommended?

Comment: Does the IBM Mobile First ecosystem hava any  LDAP services?
Is there a recommendation for any particular LDAP product?

Comment: Not that I know of, however it is very common for organizations to use their own servers for such a mechanism... You can also look into social login: https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/blog/2016/04/06/social-login-with-ibm-mobilefirst-platform-foundation/ - or just have your own simple database...